# Pivot WP 8.1 VisualStateManager for selected items doesn't work?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Why this doesn't work on Windows Phone 8.1 RT (no effect on header opacity):

```
        <Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding PivotDefinition}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="subheader" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="subheader" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.4"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="subheader" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        </Pivot>
```

Comment: Put your state changes in the style control template as opposed to the header datatemplate and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but when I do that I get that DataTemplate is expected...

Comment: I'll have to go yank out the templates a bit later to see for sure but there should be a ContentPresenter or HeaderPanel, or something else in there you would target other than "subheader" so make sure you have the right target set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is the bug in WP, so I skipped whole VisualStateManager and bound Opacity directly from ViewModel to subheader.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with customised Pivot Header in Windows Phone Runtime. The Silverlight 8.1 Pivot works correctly.

I'm not aware of any workarounds that would give the control you are looking for. You can override the Pivot's theme colours app-wide in the app.xaml's resources. The presenter for the header is encapsulated in the PivotHeaderPanel and so their full appearance cannot be modified in the base Pivot style outside of the HeaderTemplate you're already using (and which doesn't dim the non-selected pages when customised, as you're seeing).

--Rob

Comment: Thanks, I know one workaround and that is to have the opacity in viewmodel and switch it there. It is not too ugly, if there are no other answers then I guess I'll post it as the answer...